# how do I put database path in Rust

Tags: rust

I firstly use:

```rust
pub static DB_FILE_NAME: &'static str = env!("DB_FILE_NAME");
```

It works well with my `makefile`(I do not know if using `makefile` with rust is a good idea):

```
test:
    DB_FILE_NAME=/tmp/db.sqlite \
    cargo run

release-build:
    DB_FILE_NAME=/var/server/db.sqlite \
    cargo build --release
```

But `rust-analyzer` puts a warning for me. It really upset me:

```
environment variable `DB_FILE_PATH` not defined
```

I know it is right, so I am trying to put the variable to `Cargo.toml` or something else that can help me choose different path when I choose different choice(`debug` or `release`). I try to search but I do not get useful infomation...

Comment: What you're doing is just fine, if it compiles. `env!` causes a compiler error if the environment lacks the variable. Rust analyzer is probably running a `cargo check` under the hood, rather than using make, so it doesn't see that the `DB_FILE_PATH` is set. You're options are to either use `#[cfg]` and define multiple statics, or use a simple build script set the variables.

Comment: You can [specify environment variables in rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#setting-runnable-environment-variables)

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the path to the DB ? It's much better to make it configurable, either asn env variable **at runtime**, config file, or an application parameter.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks! but it depends editor config...

Comment: @Aiden4 build script sounds good! I will try it! Thanks for you advice.